# Android: Custom list view list element click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, custom-adapter

I am developing an application with custom adapter for list view, in which the data is coming from server. The custom adapter is consist of image view minimum two and maximum four depends on data from server. as shown in image.

[image: List item]

As according to functionality every image view is having on click listener.

**The issue is** When i click on list first item - first image view it get selected, but when i click list second item - second image view then the firt items selection changes. The selection of first item changes from first image view to second.

And this goes on.

I tried notifydatasetchange() also, as my data is stored in list view and also i am saving the selected items image view number in list view on selection.

What should i do now. Please suggest me.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: @Jorge Mendez: Sorry but i can not.

Comment: @ManojFegde Without your code, it won't be easy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code that actually works (already tested on a device). This might help you to solve your problem. The only variation is that the size of amount of images in each item might be different. Hopefully this will helpful:

HomeActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static final int LIST_SIZE = 10;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view)).setAdapter(new SelectableItemsListAdapter(this, LIST_SIZE));
  }

  private class SelectableItemsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    private int mSize;
    private boolean []mSelectionArray;

    public SelectableItemsListAdapter(Context context, int size) {
      super(context, R.layout.list_item);
      mSize = size;
      int selectableItems = mSize * 4;
      mSelectionArray = new boolean[selectableItems];
      for(int i = 0 ; i < selectableItems ; i++){
        mSelectionArray[i] = false;
      }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
      }

      int actualPosition = position * 4;
      View textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
      textView.setTag(actualPosition);
      textView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
      textView.setSelected(mSelectionArray[actualPosition]);

      actualPosition++;
      textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
      textView.setTag(actualPosition);
      textView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
      textView.setSelected(mSelectionArray[actualPosition]);

      actualPosition++;
      textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_3);
      textView.setTag(actualPosition);
      textView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
      textView.setSelected(mSelectionArray[actualPosition]);

      actualPosition++;
      textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_4);
      textView.setTag(actualPosition);
      textView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
      textView.setSelected(mSelectionArray[actualPosition]);

      return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return mSize;
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        int actualPosition = (int) v.getTag();
        mSelectionArray[actualPosition] = !v.isSelected();
        v.setSelected(mSelectionArray[actualPosition]);
      }
    };

  }

}
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="150dp"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text_1"
              android:text="Text 1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:textColor="@android:color/black"
              android:background="@drawable/selectable_item"
              android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text_2"
              android:text="Text 2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:textColor="@android:color/black"
              android:background="@drawable/selectable_item"
              android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text_3"
              android:text="Text 3"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:textColor="@android:color/black"
              android:background="@drawable/selectable_item"
              android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text_4"
              android:text="Text 4"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:textColor="@android:color/black"
              android:background="@drawable/selectable_item"
              android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

selectable_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false">
        <color android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <color android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to do multiple selections? If so, you can set the`android:choiceMode` attribute of your ListView.

Comment: No multiple selection app required. Selection one option of one list item at a time. After selection one option it is having some task to do. Then select other option.

Comment: I don't think I can help you if you don't post any code.